# How to use AvroParquetReader inside a Flink application?

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, parquet, flink-streaming

I am having trouble using `AvroParquetReader` inside a Flink Application. (flink>=1.15)

**Motivaton (AKA why I want to use it)**

According to [official doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/parquet/) one can read Parquet files in Flink into `FileSource`. However, I only want to write a function to load parquet file into Avro records without creating a `DataStreamSource`. In particular, I want to load parquet files into `FileInputFormat` which is a complete separate API (for some weird reasons). (And I could not see easily how one could cast `BulkFormat` or `StreamFormat` into it, if one dig one level deeper.)

Therefore, it would much simpler if one use `org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetReader` to read it directly.

**Error description**

However, I found this error after run the Flink application locally: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found`.

This is quite unexpected, since the `flink-s3-hadoop-fs` jar has already been loaded inside the plugin system (and the file path has already been added to `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` as well). So not only flink knows where it is, so should the local hadoop as well.

Comments:

1. Without this `AvroParquetReader`, the Flink app can write to S3 without problem.
2. The Hadoop is not a flink shaded one, but installed separately with version 2.10.

Would love to hear if you have some insights about this.

ParquetAvroReader should be able to read the parquet files without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an official `hadoop` guide that has some potential fixes for the issue and can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.md). If I recall correnctly this issue was cause by some Hadoop AWS dependencies missing.

Comment: Thanks @Dominik for the pointer. I have solved this problem by adding `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws` to the Flink App fat jar. It was a bit confusing in the beginning on how Flink uses hadoop classes from all different places if you run it locally. But it turns out to be a rather simple problem in the end.

Comment: Yeah, working directly with Hadoop Inputs in Flink has kept me awake for few nights...